# Allow ability to populate ServerWebExchange.LogPrefix in Spring WebFlux for UniqueRequestId logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Spring `Webflux` offer Handlers which take a `ServerRequest` and is from where we implement our code. As per the following article Spring has a `LogId` concept which seems to be a what I refer to as a `UniqueRequestId`. When an exception is thrown the framework will put the `LogId` into the log entry via `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` / `ServerWebExchange`. My situation relates to having many services calling each other and sharing a `UniqueRequestId`. So rather than Spring generating this ID we'd like a way to set the `LogId` via a HTTP Request Header e.g. X-Request-Id. My reason is so that the logs from one service can be related to the logs from another service. I can't find any articles on how to achieve this.

Some related background: I've managed a 90% partial alternate solution of getting a `UniqueRequestId` into the logs by setting the `UniqueRequestId` into MDC (`ThreadLocal`) and then passing it through the reactive chain based on this feature (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context -> see "*Adding a Context to a Reactive Sequence*"). This works for code handled within my reactive sequence + handler but if my code throws an `Exception` or `Mono.error(...)` then it seems the Spring WebFlux framework dispatches the logging to an async thread and therefore both the MDC and Context are lost. Hence I was hoping to bridge the final issue by poking my `UniqueRequestId` into the `LogId`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-logging-id

**Spring:**
Boot: 2.4.1, Web + WebFlux: 5.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Do you want specifically to implement yourself the correlation part using a `UniqueRequestId`?

If you only want the feature of being able to **keep track** of your processing on your services or across services then you should look at `tracing` solutions which can be commonly found in `application performance monitoring` libraries.

I think you could use `spring-cloud-sleuth` with only log correlation (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#only-sleuth-log-correlation)

Sleuth supports reactor (spring webflux), it'll automatically add some data to your logs

1. `trace.id` a `trace` represents an operation, or a data flow, that can happen on several services. To me this is what you are looking for, this trace is made to be sent to other services so that they reuse it in their logs. Allowing you to track a particular call over several services.
2. `transaction.id` a `transaction` represents an operation, or a data flow inside the same service.

For example (the code below does not work, its just to give you an idea):

- serviceA makes an HTTP call to serviceB, both running in different containers / JVM

```java
public class serviceA() {

  private final ServiceBClient serviceBClient;

  @Get
  public Flux<Cat> getSomething() {
    log.info('Calling serviceB');
    return serviceBClient
      .listAllCats()
      .then(() -> {    log.info('Called serviceB') });
  }

}
```

```java
public class serviceB() {

  private final CatRepository catRepository;

  @Get
  public Flux<Cat> listCats() {
    log.info('Asking for cats');
    return catRepository.listAll()
     .doOnSuccess(() -> { log.info('Request success!') })
  }

}
```

Below are example with custom log message (only care for the trace.id)
serviceA.log

```
[INFO] .... Calling serviceB, trace.id=1321313543121, transaction.id=123546   
[INFO] .... Called serviceB, trace.id=1321313543121, transaction.id=123546
```

serviceB.log

```
[INFO] .... Asking for cats, trace.id=1321313543121, transaction.id=224465   
[INFO] .... Called serviceB, trace.id=1321313543121, transaction.id=224465
```

2. `transaction.id`, a transaction represent an operation on a specific service.

Sleuth should also the trace.id to error logs

Comment: I came across Spring Sleuth in my resource. I ruled it out because we have services in all sorts of languages/technologies e.g. .Net/JS AWS Lambdas etc. I'll take another look at it and see if I can "massage" it to achieve my requirement. FYI: we are using New Relic for Distributed Tracing so that covers the "viewing" of the trace. I just need to solve how to get the `UniqueRequestId` into the logs so you can cross reference logs to traces and investigate errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone else: I took another look at Spring Sleuth (because it was suggested in another answer) and it solves the origin of my question which is to get a UniqueTracingId into the logs. However this answer still doesn't solve my original question which I would like answered.

It is possible to only use just the Logging feature of Sleuth if you just add the "starter" dependency `implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:3.0.0'`.
In the end we decided to use it as an interim solution because it seem to pass the traceId throughout most of the reactive chain and puts it into MDC which makes it easy to print it into the logs e.g. via LogBack `%X{traceId}`.

So the steps are:

1. add Spring Sleuth to your project
2. add the TraceIdPropagator code below to your project
3. add something like this to Logback (or work out equivalant for Log4J) `<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X{traceId} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>`

```
@Component
@Log4j2
class TraceIdPropagator extends Propagation.Factory implements Propagation<String> {

    private static final long NON_NEEDED_VALUE = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<String> keys() {
        return Arrays.asList(ContractHandler.REQUEST_ID_HEADER);
    }

    @Override
    public <R> TraceContext.Injector<R> injector(Setter<R, String> setter) {
        return (traceContext, request) -> {
            setter.put(request, ContractHandler.REQUEST_ID_HEADER, traceContext.traceIdString());
        };
    }

    @Override
    public <R> TraceContext.Extractor<R> extractor(Getter<R, String> getter) {
        return request -> {
            String xRequestId = getter.get(request, ContractHandler.REQUEST_ID_HEADER);

            long traceId;

            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(xRequestId)) {
                traceId = NON_NEEDED_VALUE;
            } else {
                try {
                    traceId = HexCodec.lowerHexToUnsignedLong(xRequestId);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Invalid X-Request-Id: " + xRequestId + ". It should be a 1 - 32 character lower case hex string.");
                }
            }

            return TraceContextOrSamplingFlags.create(TraceContext.newBuilder()
                .traceId(traceId)
                .spanId(NON_NEEDED_VALUE)
                .build());
            };
    }

    @Override
    public <K> Propagation<K> create(KeyFactory<K> keyFactory) {
        return StringPropagationAdapter.create(this, keyFactory);
    }

}
```